# What is the difference between kinetic friction and internal kinetic friction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, friction

I came across the following question in my homework assignment:

Which of the following statements is TRUE for a system comprising of two bodies in contact exerting
frictional force on each other :

(A) total work done by static friction on whole system is always zero.
(B) work done by static friction on a body is always zero
(C) work done by kinetic friction on a body is always negative
(D) total work done by internal kinetic friction on whole system is always negative

I understand the options A and B, but am confused between C and D.

Comment: Please provide a diagram.  Say m1 sits on top of m2.  Is m2 on the immoveable ground, or is m2 on another mass m3 that can move?

Comment: This is all the information provided, but based on similar questions I did in a friction assignment, I would assume that that m2 is on an immovable smooth surface with m1 on top of it.